# Unable to connect MySQL using 'root'@'IP_Address' in Vagrant

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant, vagrantfile, mysql-5.7

I am trying to connect `MySQL` using `Vagrant VM`. 
I can access `MySQL` using *`root@localhost`* in vagrant ssh , but when I connect using *`root@192.168.33.10`* which is the IP used for Vagrant VM, I am getting `access denied` error.

**This is my Vagrant file settings:**

```
  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.

   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
   config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3306

  # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
  # using a specific IP.

   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

**root@192.168.33.10 is already added in mySQL, and permissions are given**

```
mysql> select User,Host from mysql.user;
+-----------+---------------+
| User      | Host          |
+-----------+---------------+
| root      | 192.168.33.10 |
| mysql.sys | localhost     |
| root      | localhost     |
+-----------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**MySQL 5.7 mysqld.cnf**

```
I have tried bind-address to '0.0.0.0' and bind-address '192.168.33.10'.
```

**Still error message shows:**

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d$ mysql -u root@192.168.33.10 -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root@192.168.33.10'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: i think you set a password when your sql connection doesn't need a password

Comment: I'm not much knowledgeable about vagrant, but are you trying to access mysql from inside the VM or from the host or another computer? I'm guessing locally, so try creating another user and connecting with it instead of root, or Grant access to this IP to root `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'192.168.33.10' IDENTIFIED BY 'P4$$WORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at the error message.  The error message is indicating that the username supplied to the MySQL server is:

```
 'user@192.168.33.10'
```

And the host that MySQL is seeing the connection from is:

```
 'localhost'
```

Here's how the MySQL client is interpreting these options:

```
 mysql -u root@192.168.33.10 -p
```

`-u user` supplies a string value, in this case, it's seeing  `'root@192.168.33.10'` as the username value. The `@` sign and the digits and dots are just part of the username string. There's no no special meaning given to those characters, it's just a string. And MySQL server is going to look for a row in the `mysql.users` table that has `User` value that matches that string. (

To find a match, MySQL is also going to look at the value in the `Host` column. That is going to have to match the host the connection is seen as coming from. What that means is `'root'@'localhost'` is a *different* user than `'root'@'192.168.33.10'`.

`-p` prompt for password

Omitted are any command options for the protocol to use, the host to connect to, the port number, etc. MySQL default when we don't supply any of that is

```
-h localhost
```

as if that is what we had specified.

---

If we want to connect to the MySQL server via the TCP/IP protocol, and not using a Unix socket, we need to specify `-h hostname` or `-h ipaddress`, or specify `--protocol=TCP`

The hostname "`localhost`: has a special meaning in MySQL. That's a connection through a Unix socket, not through the loopback IP address we might expect.

---

For example, to connect to the MySQL server on the local machine, listening on the default port 3306, using the loopback IP address:

```
  mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

Most of this information is covered pretty well in the MySQL Reference Manual.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html

Also, by default, MySQL uses reverse DNS lookup to resolve IP addresses to hostnames.

If we want to use IP addresses in the `Host` column of the mysql.users table, we need to disable reverse DNS lookup. We do that by including this option:

```
skip_name_resolve
```

In the `my.cnf` configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

Right command is

```
mysql -u root -h 192.168.33.10 -p
```